# d3.js tree with json string dont recognize as Array

Tags: javascript, c#, json, serialization, d3.js

I am using d3.js in order to show a tree.

The problem is the next :

If in the javascript I do 
`var data1 = [
        { "name" : "Level 2: A", "parent":"Top Level" },
    ];`

This work well (I mean the view show me the tree). However if I have the json string in the view :
 `String dataTree = (String) ViewData["dataTree"];`

and then in the Javascript I do :
`var data = '@dataTree';`

The console return an error

> Uncaught TypeError: data.reduce is not a function

And in the source I see

> var data = '[{"name":"root"]

(the var with &quot ).

Below I copy the code which I use in the view to show the tree with d3.js :

```
var data = '@dataTree';

// *********** Convert flat data into a nice tree ***************
// create a name: node map
var dataMap = data.reduce(function(map, node) {
    map[node.name] = node;
    return map;
}, {});

// create the tree array
var treeData = [];
data.forEach(function(node) {
    // add to parent
    var parent = dataMap[node.parent];
    if (parent) {
        // create child array if it doesn't exist
        (parent.children || (parent.children = []))
            // add node to child array
            .push(node);
    } else {
        // parent is null or missing
        treeData.push(node);
    }
});

// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];

update(root);

function update(source) {

    // Compute the new tree layout.
    var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
        links = tree.links(nodes);

    // Normalize for fixed-depth.
    nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

    // Declare the nodes…
    var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

    // Enter the nodes.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
            return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .style("fill", "#fff");

    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d) { 
            return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { 
            return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
        .style("fill-opacity", 1);

    // Declare the links…
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

    // Enter the links.
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", diagonal);

}
```

UPDATED : The problem is the dataTree doesn't recognize as a array. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a C# value to HTML/JavaScript, you'd better use an input value.

In view, you do:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(t=> t.yourdata)
```

In JavaScript, you do:

```
var data = $('yourdata').val();
```

The error you're getting means you're doing `array.reduce` on a non-array variable.

Comment: Can you copy the code of Html.HiddenFor  and the code of javascript?